# the browser saved my javascript function name and buged my site

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, caching

Hello guys today i spent half the day trying to figure out why my website went crazy , i finnaly managed to figure out and now i am wondering what can i do to prevent this in the future.
Here is what happened : 
I got a simple JS file

```
function standardAlert(  ) 
     {

     grid1.save()
     window.alert( "The information has been saved!" )
 }
```

Now today i been doing some changes on the site and i also added another function with a different name that shows a different window.alert

From that moment on every time i clicked my save button i had this error on my error log :

"Invalid postback or callback argument. Event validation is enabled using  in configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page...."

I been going crazy.. checking old backups changing back and forth the changes i made today.
 Eventully few minutes ago i finnaly found out the problem.
The browser saved up the old function name and everytime i clicked the save button which had an onclientclick event assosiated with the old function name i got this error. Ofcourse i also uplodaed the different versions of the JS file as well but it didnt matter for the browser!

So my question is how can i prevent such things in the future? 
P.S  I also had this with pictures that didnt show up because the browser used the old 1 from his local storage.

Forgot to mention that i solved this by clearing out my brows er cache! but what will happen in the future when ppl will be using the site and maybe i will have to change a JS function name again? or maybe a picture? 
I dont want to have to say to ppl that they need to clear their cache as a solution. I am sure there is something i am missing i am just still very new to this.

I am using MS sql server 2000

Comment: do an iisreset after making such a change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you change a file on your server, you need the server to send the new version of this file to the clients (browsers) when they request it.

This can be achieved in a variety of ways - the best one in most cases involves setting up your server to handle changed files (i.e. compare timestamps and decide when it's appropriate to send a new version of the file rather than telling the client that they have the most up-to-date version). But this does depend on your server environment (which you haven't described in your question).

However there is normally a way to achieve this by changing stuff on the client side only. When requesting a file, append a unique string to it, in a way that will be ignored by the server. This way, the client cannot possibly think that it already has an up-to-date version of the file that it's requesting. So instead of getting, for example:

http://example.com/myfile.js

you would get

http://example.com/myfile.js?_t=1234567

where the number at the end could be Date.now() converted to a string, for example.

However this would effectively stop any caching of myfile.js, and would have an impact on your bandwidth usage. So fix it on the server if possible - how to do it depends on which server you are using though.

Comment: Thanks alot i didnt know that! i will edit my question now , i am using ms sql server 2000